# Compiling error when importing a custom library

Tags: angular, devextreme

I'm currently developing a library that use `DevExtreme` to show some grids.

I've created the library and this is what the project `package.json` looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "devextreme": "18.2.8",
    "devextreme-angular": "18.2.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1",
    "jquery": "3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.25",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.37.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
```

This is the library's `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "data-grid-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
  }
}
```

This is the module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DataGridLibComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DxDataGridModule,
    DxTextBoxModule
  ],
  exports: [DataGridLibComponent]
})
export class DataGridLibModule {
  public static forRoot(config): ModuleWithProviders<DataGridLibModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: DataGridLibModule,
      providers: [DataGridLibService, {provide: DataGridServiceConfig, useValue: config}]
    };
  }
}
```

The code stuff is irrelevant. 
If I build this library and import it into a project it gives me this error :

> ERROR in The target entry-point "data-grid-lib" has missing
>   dependencies:
>    - devextreme/data/custom_store
>    - devextreme-angular

The solution to solve this error is simple yet non-sense to me:

Install the devExtreme dependencies into the project as well.

What I'm not getting is this:

The library holds the DevExtreme logic, the project doesn't. So am I doing something wrong or both the `library` and the `project` **must** have the same dependencies?

`package.json` of the test project where I get the error:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have installed `devextreme-angular` but you didn't install it's dependencies.
try installing dependencies using `npm install devextreme@19.2`. Here i'm using current version. I think that should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes that's solving the problem. I just don't get it why I have to do it. I mean, logically is the library that's using the DevExtreme library. I'm not quite familiar with libraries, but I believe there's a way to leave the DevExtreme part only to the library, without the main application having to install its dependencies.

Comment: So I think `devextreme` has separate npm for dependencies and 
it has separate  npm for all the ui libraries it can be integrated with.
but if you want to install everything just by one npm i think this will do the job
`npx -p devextreme-cli devextreme new angular-app app-name`